# How to determine why a GameplayAbility failed to activate

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-gameplay-ability-system

To get notified about the reason why a [GameplayAbility](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Gameplay/GameplayAbilitySystem/GameplayAbility) failed to activate, it is possible to assign a function to the delegate `UAbilitySystemComponent::AbilityFailedCallbacks()`. It contains a tag parameter. This parameter can be used to determine the reason why `UAbilitySystemComponent::TryActivateAbility()` failed, be it either:

- the ability is on *cooldown*
- the *cost* couldn’t be afforded
- *blocked* by other abilities
- the AbilitySystemComponent is missing required *GameplayTags*

However, when testing, the tag in the delegate is empty (or the delegate isn't even fired).

1. Where does this tag come from?
2. How to set that tag?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Those tags are part of `UAbilitySystemGlobals`. It has tags for:

- actor is being dead `ActivateFailIsDeadTag`
- on cooldown `ActivateFailCooldownTag`
- insufficient costs `ActivateFailCostTag`
- blocked by other abilities `ActivateFailTagsBlockedTag`
- missing required tags `ActivateFailTagsMissingTag`
- invalid networking settings `ActivateFailNetworkingTag`

(2) They can be set by (example for cost)

1. Set the tags in `DefaultGame.ini`, using the corresponding `FName` (example for costs):

   ```
   [/Script/GameplayAbilities.AbilitySystemGlobals]
   ActivateFailCostName=My.Test.Tag
   ```
2. Make sure, the GameplayTag exists, e.g. in `DefaultGameplayTags.ini`

   ```
   +GameplayTagList=(Tag="My.Test.Tag",DevComment="")
   ```
3. Initialize those tags by calling `UAbilitySystemGlobals::Get().InitGlobalData()`, e.g. in the constructor of your `UGameInstance` subclass.

### How does that work

Example for costs:

in `UGameplayAbility::CanActivateAbility()` -> `UGameplayAbility::CheckCost()`:

- `UAbilitySystemGlobals::ActivateFailCostTag` is applied to optional out param `OptionalRelevantTags` if costs can’t be afforded
- this tag is used in `UAbilitySystemComponent::NotifyAbilityFailed()` which
- fires the delegate `UAbilitySystemComponent::AbilityFailedCallbacks`

This is similar for the other cases mentioned above (cooldown, block, …).